# Scrollview Not working for Cardview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, nestedscrollview

I have been working on a app, but stuck in a xml layout issue, the scrollview I usually use is not working when I am using the Card views inside a linear layout, I looked up in google and found out about NestedScrollview, it still wont work, app force closes, could some one tell me what exactly am I doing wrong, and correct. It will be very helpful.

> activity_items_details.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItemDetailsName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:paddingTop="65dp"
        android:paddingBottom="65dp"
        tools:text="Item Name"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Qty"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvItemDetailsQty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="Qty:"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PO #"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvItemDetailsPono"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="PO #:"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Supplier"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvItemDetailsSupplier"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="Supplier:"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Contact"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvItemDetailsContact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="Contact:"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Transporter"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvItemDetailsTransport"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="Transporter:"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LR #"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvItemDetailsLrno"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="LR #:"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LR #"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvItemDetailsRemarks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="Remarks:"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: why `NestedScrollView` inside another `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: Sorry, Edited the xml, happened something while copying

Comment: so now your `NestedScrollView` has multiple child views?

Comment: Beginner at Android, did I do something wrong?

Comment: ScrollView can only have one direct child. Put that outer LinearLayout inside NestedScrollView. I guess then it should work i.e  <NestedScrollView>
 <LinearLayout>
  <CardView></CardView>
 </LinearLayout>
</NestedSrollView>

Comment: I was trying something like this I found from a different question https://github.com/ngocchung/NestedScrollView/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/content_main.xml

Comment: did you try to run your app? (and watch the `logcat`)?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error you mentioned

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fayaz.uniabex/com.fayaz.uniabex.ItemDetailsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: Look at my comment, it's a small issue

Comment: Okay, I was just checking the official documentation, and found that its actually to scroll inside another layout, correct me if I am wrong, I just wanted the cards to scroll, which are not showing up, because there are 8 of them, only 5 of them are showing up in small screen phones, like my moto e

Comment: User RecyclerView with CardView as item

Comment: @Parshu, I tried you workaround, by removing the Outer Linear, it still wont work, could you please explain the Recyclerview solution you mentioned above.

Comment: Check this site : http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: Thank you @Parshu, I will look into and try to fix the code, thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put LinearLayout after NestedScrollView like below if you don't want to try RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple child views inside `NestedScrollView`, `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView` can host only one child.

To fix your layout, put all the stuffs into any ViewGroup such as `LinearLayout` / `RelativeLayout` and then arrange your views accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You should implement it like this :

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/activity_Recipe_detail_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical">
               // do what ever you need here
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

hope this help